# How to run Jupyter Notebook in a vertual environment?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, virtualenv

I am new to jupyter notebook. I want to run my notebooks using a virtual environment. I installed tensorflow in my environment but when I run it using environment kernel it cannot find tensorflow.

I am doing a project with tensorflow. So I created a vertual environment with python 3.9 named "tensorflow_env". So to run codes using this environment I added this environment kernel with `ipython kernel install --user --name=tensorflow_env`. I have already installed tensorflow in my environment. But while trying to import tensorflow from notebooks .ipynb file it shows an error.

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 1
----> 1 import tensorflow as tf
      3 print(tf.__version__)

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

I tried running the server after activating the environment. At first I tried it in cmd, then also in notebook terminal. My jupyter notebook is installed as part of anaconda. I opened it from command promt both with admin previlage and without admin previlage. I also tried directly launching the app.

Previously I had an error showing it cannot find the pip.exe file inside the environment. After forcefully reinstalling it now I can find it. I checked it has tensorflow installed.

I checked various questions but I cannot find answer to my specific problem.

It seems like I did not have `ipykernel` installed. After running `pip install ipykernel` and `python -m ipykernel install --user --name tensorflow_env` now I can find tensorflow. But now it is showing type error.

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent 
call last)
Cell In[1], line 1
----> 1 import tensorflow as tf
      3 print(tf.__version__)
```

At the very end of this error it is showing,

```
TypeError: Descriptors cannot not be created directly.
If this call came from a _pb2.py file, your generated code is out 
of date and must be regenerated with protoc >= 3.19.0.
If you cannot immediately regenerate your protos, some other 
possible workarounds are:
1. Downgrade the protobuf package to 3.20.x or lower.
2. Set PROTOCOL_BUFFERS_PYTHON_IMPLEMENTATION=python (but this 
will use pure-Python parsing and will be much slower).
```

Comment: Have you selected your environment in Jupiter (after you open the notebook) - under the kernel menu you can choose environments. It will also usually show the environment/kernel that is active somewhere about the top right of the screen.

Comment: Please post the error as a text, and not an image.

Comment: @topsail yes I did select the kernel. But its not showing any different.

Answer (score 0):

I just found this closed question https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/10051. With new update on python it is creating some problem for `protobuf` and some other google cloud packages. In order to avoid this just install an older version. I installed `protobuf=3.20` and it solved the problem. Thank you for your attention.